# Python Custom Class to use GCP Client

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-class

I want to use a gcp client in a my own defined class. Could you show me how to define a client in class using the gcp client ?

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery 

class connect_data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
        self.df = None
        try:
            self.file_path = 'cred.json'
            os.path.isfile(self.file_path)
        except:
            raise ValueError('not found')

    def setup_qcp_client(self):
        if self.client is None:
            self.client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(self.file_path)
            
    def setup_query(self, text):
        query_output = self.client.query(text[0])
        query_result = query_output.result()
        self.df = query_result.to_dataframe()
```

When I call setup_query method from connect_data class it returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setup_query' error.

```
query = ["SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_2014`"]
a = connect_data()
a = a.setup_qcp_client()
a.setup_query(query[0])
```

Comment: You do not return anything from `setup_query`. And you should not assign `a.setup_qcp_client()` to `a`.

Comment: Yes ı see the point. I will add a return statement. Thank you luk. ı have one question. Does this class definition seem appropriate to you ? I just want to understand ways to define and improve my knowledge about it.

Comment: No, the class is quite bad. It is stateful and does not follow naming patterns. The client should be created in the constructor or passed in, the `df` must not be a class member, the class should be called `ConnectData` if anything.

Comment: One more question. Why df should not be a class member ?